# View BLOB data which contains text in XML format

Tags: oracle

How to view a BLOB data, can i export it to text file? I am using Oracle SQL developer 5.1. When i tried

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(COLNAME)) 
  from user_settings where <fieldname>=...
```

It returns the following error: `ORA-06502 PL/SQL : numeric or value error : raw variable length too long`

The BLOB contains text in XML format.

Answer (score 6):

To view xml data stored as a BLOB, do the following;

1. Open the table view, with the Data tab selected
2. Double click on the column field value, and a pencil button should appear in the field.  Click the pencil button. [image: Pencil Button]
3. The Edit Value window should open, click checkbox for 'View As: Text'.  From this window you can also save out any particular file data you require. [image: Select the view type]

PS: I'm running Oracle SQL Developer version 3.1.05

Answer (score 3):

Cause it over the size of the display field. It needs to set the size 
You add `1500` for the `substr`, it should be work.

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(colname,1500))
from user_settings where <row_id>=...
```

Answer (score 1):

BLOB data is typically just... a binary blob of data.

Sure, you can export it to a text file by converting it to some kind of text representation... But what if it is an image?

jaganath: You need to sit down and figure out what it is you're dealing with, and then find out what it is you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOCLOB

But if it is XML, why store it in a BLOB rather than an XMLType (or CLOB)

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems that the blob length is too long to fit into a varchar. You could do the conversion in your application code and write the XML into a String or file.